# Java - Hourglass

Tags: java

I'm missing by just a little bit. What I want:

```
*******
 *****
  ***
   *
  ***
 *****
*******
```

What I'm getting

```
*******
 *****
  ***
   *
   *
  ***
 *****
*******
```

The code

```
public class HD404 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int N = StdIn.readInt();
        int x = N*2-1;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
                StdOut.print(" ");
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < x; k++) {
                StdOut.print("*");
            }
            x-=2;
            StdOut.println();
        }

        x = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < N-1; j++) {
                StdOut.print(" ");
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < x; k++) {
                StdOut.print("*");
            }
            x += 2;
            StdOut.println();
        }

    }
}
```

Right now I'm mostly just guessing and I just can't pin point my error. What am I missing here?

Comment: did you try a debugger? just take a look what happens in your code after the first single * is printed

Comment: Up-voted. This one's better than 99% of similar posts because he's showing that he really tried.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are starting to draw the bottom of the hourglass with 1 asterisk (`x = 1`) instead of 3.

The second issue is that the bottom of the hourglass only has `N-2` lines, not `N-1` so the loop should start at 1 instead of 0. This is because the line with a single asterisk was already drawn in the upper-half.

Corrected code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int N = StdIn.readInt();
    int x = N*2-1;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            StdOut.print(" ");
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < x; k++) {
            StdOut.print("*");
        }
        x-=2;
        StdOut.println();
    }

    x = 3; // <-- not 1 here, the first line has 3 asterisks
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) { // <-- i starts at 1 because the first line was already drawn in the upper half
        for (int j = i; j < N-1; j++) {
            StdOut.print(" ");
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < x; k++) {
            StdOut.print("*");
        }
        x += 2;
        StdOut.println();
    }

}
```

---

As a side-note, you could rewrite this code a lot shorter by making the following observations:

- There are `x` lines to draw so we can loop from `0` to `x` included (to respect the symmetry) and skip the middle line so as not to draw it twice
- For every line, there are `x` columns to draw and it is either a space or a `*`.
- For every line, `*` is drawn only if the current column is between `min(i, x-i)` and `max(i, x-i)` (if we're in the upper-part, `i < x-i` and if we're in the bottom-part, `i > x-i`).

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N = 4;
    int x = 2 * N - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
        if (i == N) continue; // skip the middle-line for it not to be drawn twice
        for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            System.out.print(j >= Math.min(i, x-i) && j < Math.max(i, x-i) ? "*" : " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
*******
 ***** 
  ***  
   *   
  ***  
 ***** 
*******
```

Answer (score 1):

The problems lays with the second part of your code where you ask to draw one star and you start at zero where you should start at one.

---

### Solution

```
x = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
```

should be replaced with

```
x = 3;
for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think up is probably to prevent the last iteration of your first outer loop, that way you'll prevent the first single star line to be shown.

I would probably do it this way:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N && x > 1; i++)
{
    /*Code of the first inner loop*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those whose still looking for a simpler and lesser code regarding hourglass challenge. This contains 2 for loops only.

You may use this as reference.

```
public static void hourGlass(int size) {
// 2 for loops only
int dimension = (size * 2) - 1, space = 0, stars = size - 1, printed = 0;

for(int i=0; i<dimension; i++) {
    int actual = space;
    for (int j=dimension; j > 0; j--) {
        if(actual > 0) {
            System.out.print(" ");
            actual--;
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("*");
            if(stars==printed) {
                actual = space;
                printed = 0;
            } else {
                actual = 1;
                printed++;
            }
        }
    }
    if(i <= size-2) { // will pattern spaces and stars from top to middle
        space++;
        stars--;
    }
    else { // will pattern spaces and stars from middle to top
        space--;
        stars++;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

}

Comment: If you want to add answer on old question please explain why is your answer better/ different from other answers. If you don't do that it will discourage anyone who scrolls to bottom to think about your code.