# how to make hourglass shape?

Tags: java, nested-loops

I need to make an hourglass shape using nested loops in java. My code can draw the essentials of the shape but is not putting any spaces to make a proper hourglass shape.
The goal shape:

```
* * * * *
 * * * *
  * * *
   * *
    *
   * *
  * * *
 * * * *
* * * * *
```

code:

```
for(int i = 5; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= 4; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
        {
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for(int j=0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
```

the output this gives me:

```
 * * * * * 
 * * * * 
 * * * 
 * * 
 * 

* *  
* * *  
* * * *  
* * * * *
```

Comment: You're printing a *fixed* number of indenting spaces. Don't you think the space-printing loop needs to use `i` to figure out how many spaces to print?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java - Hourglass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34109810/java-hourglass)

Answer (score -1):

In the following solution you can change the size of the hourglass according to `size` variable.

```java
public class Main {

    public static int size = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = size; i > 0; i--) {
            printLineByIndex(i);
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int i = 2; i < size + 1; i++) {
            printLineByIndex(i);
            if(i != size) { // do not put empty line at the end of the output
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printLineByIndex(int i) {
        for (int k = 0; k < size - i; k++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--){
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
* * * * * 
 * * * * 
  * * * 
   * * 
    * 
   * * 
  * * * 
 * * * * 
* * * * *
```

Answer (score -1):

This is likely beyond your current level, but to show you how simply it can be done in Java 11+, so you have something to strive towards, this is one way to do it:

```java
static void printHourglass(int size) {
    for (int i = 1 - size; i < size; i++)
        System.out.println(" ".repeat(size - Math.abs(i) - 1) + "* ".repeat(Math.abs(i)) + "*");
}
```

*Output with `printHourglass(5)`*

```
* * * * *
 * * * *
  * * *
   * *
    *
   * *
  * * *
 * * * *
* * * * *
```

*Output with `printHourglass(5)`*

```
* * * * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * * * *
  * * * * * * * *
   * * * * * * *
    * * * * * *
     * * * * *
      * * * *
       * * *
        * *
         *
        * *
       * * *
      * * * *
     * * * * *
    * * * * * *
   * * * * * * *
  * * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
```